# Como fazer busca pelo Id no mongodb Com condição

Tags: mongodb, meteor, graphql

Como fazer uma busca no mongo com parâmetros de condição, tipo:

```
Collection.find({userId}, {done: true}).fetch();
```

Desse jeito que eu escrevi quero retornar todos os documentos que tem o 
**done** igual a true, fazendo uma busca no id do Usuario.

Eu tenho na collection um **userID**, **_id** da Collection, e o campo **done**

Estou usando Meteor e grahql, essa é meu *resolver*

```
 Query: {
    async taskCompleted(obj, args, {userId}) {
        return await Tasks.find({userId}).fetch();
    }
}
```

Nesse trecho de código, ele retorna todas as tarefas do usuario em questão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A denotação correcta seria.

```
var user_id = "as23df56hg";

//retorna um array de Tasks do respectivo query
var tasks = Tasks.find({ "userId" : user_id, "done" : true }).fetch();
```

Podes tambem usar o `findOne`

```
var user_id = "as23df56hg";

//retorna a primeira Task do respectivo query
var task = Tasks.findOne({ "userId" : user_id, "done" : true });
```

---

**Importante**

[Como usar selectores de organização](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#sortspecifiers)

[Como usar selectores de campo](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#fieldspecifiers)